# how to read a binary file into a serialized list C#

Tags: c#, winforms, file-io

I have a list of events and I save it in a binary file using this code

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    using (BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs))
    {
        foreach (MacroEvent macroEvent in events)
        {
            w.Write(macroEvent.TimeSinceLastEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

but I'm confused to how I read and get it back again in a list?

Comment: Why not just use a `BinarySerializer` and write straight to disk using that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following recipe is a good guide on how to implement ISerializable for an object you want to serialize and deserialize with a BinaryFormatter:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-serialize-objects-to-a-file

Here is the NET 4.0 documentation on BinaryFormatter:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx

and ISerializable:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Sequential file access File using serialization
Add
Using system.Io
Using system.Runtime.Serialzation.Formatters.Binary
Using System.Runtime.Serialization
Using Macro Events
name space created fileform  : macroform
//Object For serializing RecordSerializables in binary format
Private Binary formatter = new binaryFormatter();
Private file stream output; //stream for writing to a file
```

Use method Deserialize to read data
Cast result of Deserialize  to type serializeable to type serializeable this cast is necessary ,because Deserialize returns a refrence of type object and need to access properties that belong to class serializable. If an error during deserialization is thrown
a serialization is thrown and the file stream is closed

Private BinaryFormatter eader = new BinaryFormatter();

Private File stream input; // stream for reading from file